# How to create a bot that simulate an SSH shell user interaction?

Tags: java, linux, shell, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to realize a bot that simulates an user that write/read on a ssh console in Java.
I'm using the JSCH library to manage the ssh connection.
This is the code from which I started:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(username, ipAddress, port);
session.setPassword(password);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect(connectionTimeoutInMillis);
Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
InputStream is = new InputStream();
OutputStream out= new OutputStream();
channel.setInputStream(is);
channel.setOutputStream(out);
channel.connect();
channel.disconnect();
is.close();
out.close();
session.disconnect();
```

Obviously the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in the code are wrong, I need to use something that the bot can use to send a String (a command line) and to receive a String(the result of the command execution), what type of streams should I use to obtain this?

Furthermore I noticed that if I send a command and use the `System.out` as output stream in many cases the output is empty because (I'm almost sure about this) the Java application terminates before that the command execution has produced the result. What is the best practice to tell to JSCH channel listener "*wait till the command execution has completed*" and then go on? I could use a `Thread.sleep(someTime)` after the command execution but I don't like much it for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a third-party [Expect-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) Java library to ease the interaction with a remote shell. Here is a good set of options you can try:

- [Expect4J](https://github.com/cverges/expect4j)
- [ExpectJ](http://expectj.sourceforge.net/)
- [Expect-for-Java](https://github.com/ronniedong/Expect-for-Java)

You can also take a look at my own open source project which I created some time ago as the successor to the existing ones. It's called [ExpectIt](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/expectit). The advantages of my library are stated on the project home page.

Here is an example of interacting with a public remote SSH service using JSch. It should be easy to adopt it for your use case.

```
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    Session session = jSch.getSession("new", "sdf.org");
    session.connect();
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");

    Expect expect = new ExpectBuilder()
            .withOutput(channel.getOutputStream())
            .withInputs(channel.getInputStream(), channel.getExtInputStream())
            .withErrorOnTimeout(true)
            .build();
    try {
        expect.expect(contains("[RETURN]"));
        expect.sendLine();
        String ipAddress = expect.expect(regexp("Trying (.*)\\.\\.\\.")).group(1);
        System.out.println("Captured IP: " + ipAddress);
        expect.expect(contains("login:"));
        expect.sendLine("new");
        expect.expect(contains("(Y/N)"));
        expect.send("N");
        expect.expect(regexp(": $"));
        expect.send("\b");
        expect.expect(regexp("\\(y\\/n\\)"));
        expect.sendLine("y");
        expect.expect(contains("Would you like to sign the guestbook?"));
        expect.send("n");
        expect.expect(contains("[RETURN]"));
        expect.sendLine();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        ssh.close();
        expect.close();
    }
```

Here is the link to the complete workable [example](https://github.com/Alexey1Gavrilov/ExpectIt/blob/master/expectit-core/src/test/java/net/sf/expectit/SshExample.java).